# MDL card height customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

So I wanted to make a card appear the same way its supposed to be done in the [Material design spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-material-response)

[Short video demo](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsaDBfZWtha0RwNGM/animation-responsiveinteraction-materialresponse-PointOfOrigin_DO_003.webm)

I have managed to do it using jquery on a simple red square (See first snippet) I simply give the desired element 0 height & width, and then animate the height & width with jquery to how big I want it to be.

The problem with any of the MDL cards is, I can't get the height to anything smaller than 200. You can check out my second snippet and see what happens when I try to set it to 150px.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Card</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p id="Box"></p>
        <button id="Start">Start</button>
        <button id="Reset">Reset</button>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $("#Start").click(function(){
                $('#Box').animate({height: "150px", width: "150px"},{duration: 1000});
            });

             $("#Reset").click(function(){
                $('#Box').animate({height: "0px", width: "0px"},{duration: 1000});
            });
            
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        #Box{
         width: 0px;
         height: 0px;
         background-color: red;
            box-shadow: -3px 1px 30px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.25);
        }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            
 $('.mdl-card').animate({height: "150px", width: "0px"},{duration: 1000});  
  $("#Start").click(function(){
    $('.mdl-card').animate({height: "150px", width: "150px"},{duration: 1000});
  });

  $("#Reset").click(function(){
    $('.mdl-card').animate({height: "0px", width: "0px"},{duration: 1000});
  });            
               
               
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp"></div>
        <button id="Start">Start</button>
        <button id="Reset">Reset</button>
    </body>
   <style>
  .mdl-card{
  margin: 5px 5px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}</style>
</html>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, maybe theres a different way to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After testing your code snippet and looked at everything that happens with Chromes developer console I found that `.mdl-card` has a `min-height` attribute in the css. Overriding that value to 0 fixed it for me.

Comment: that was what I did yes, but maybe not do it globally (to avoid other problems that might occur by doing so), in other word not doing it in .mdl-card but in your own class

Comment: Or I assign an Id to the card I want to do this with, would that work too?